# Julia - How to check if condition variable is set

Tags: julia

How do I perform a non-blocking check to see if a Threads.Condition variable is set?

```
import Base.Threads

exitCondition = Condition()

while True:
    if isset(exitCondition):
        break
    end
end

notify(exitCondition)
```

Comment: This code looks like a mix of Julia and Python syntax...